# Can a transaction that only sends Ether (no contract interactions) generate logs?

Tags: transactions, out-of-gas, logs

Are there any circumstances in which a simple transactions, sending a value in Ether and nothing else, could generate logs?

What types of possible errors can this type of transaction throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and unless you send less than 21k gas, none.

Writing to the log bloom requires using the `log` opcodes, which of course means there must be some code involved. Exceptions require there to be code as well.